# Underline a string until the end of the line

Tags: bash

I have the following code which displays a message based on whether or not the last command was executed successfully (which is prepended to `PS1`):

```
function previous_command() {
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\033[1;4;32mCommand successful\033[00m"
    else
        echo -e "\033[1;4;31mCommand failed with exit code $exit_code\033[00m"
    fi
}
```

What I want to do is have the underline extend all the way to the edge of the current terminal window, like this:

[image: Bash draw underline until the edge of the terminal window]

Assuming the exit code is one character long, I can hard-code it to 80 characters by just adding spaces, but this fails if I resize the window or get an exit code of 10 or greater.

How can I make this function *dynamically* continue the line to the edge of the terminal window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can left align a string with spaces to 42 characters with `printf "%-42s"`. You can get the window width with `$COLUMNS`. Putting them together, we get:

```
printf "\033[1;4;31m%-${COLUMNS}s\033[00m" "Command failed with $RANDOM"
```

No matter how many digits the (here random) number is, the line always extends all the way to the edge.

Comment: Note: $COLUMNS is not available in many distributions when accessed within a script. E.g: `$ echo $COLUMNS` returns 117. Placing that same command in a script fails.

Comment: According to `time`, it executes virtually instantly on my machine, excellent!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That can be fixed with `"\033[1;4;31m%-$(tput cols)s\033[00m"`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I just wanted to make sure that was clear in the thread.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin that's because `COLUMNS` is not exported. You may mark it as exported in an initialization file. Anyways, this is not relevant here since it's not to be called from within a script.

Answer (score 1):

This works but is probably not the best solution:

```
function previous_command() {
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        COLOR=2
        RESPONSE="Command successful"
    else
        COLOR=1
        RESPONSE="Command failed with exit code $?"
    fi
    COLS=`tput cols`
    LENGTH=${#RESPONSE}
    while [ $LENGTH -lt $COLS ]
    do
        RESPONSE+=" "
        LENGTH=$[$LENGTH+1]
    done
    echo -e "$(tput setaf $COLOR ; tput smul)$RESPONSE\e[00m"
}
```

This will underline to the width of the console as it currently stands but not if you resize it.

Comment: Don't forget to reset the color after you are done with it. Don't want to mess up the formatting of the next command that comes along. ;)

Comment: Updated answer with an attribute reset at the end

Comment: My eyes hurt when I look at this…